# Access a public Google Calendar with C#

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have a WPF application in which a want to access a public Google Calendar that I have added to my Google account in order to look for upcoming events. I used the [quickstart provided by Google](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet) but I can't figure out how to select which calendar I want to access.  How do I choose which calendar to get events from?

**UPDATE:** Moved code and solution to [a separate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44654386/4826084).

Comment: Please post the code that you have so far.

Comment: So, now I have added the code also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was simple to access the calendar! I just had to change the `primary` in

```
EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
```

to the calendar ID for the calendar I want to access. Now I can get my events from my primary calendar!

## Solution:

```
public class GoogleCalendar
{
    static string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly };
    static string ApplicationName = "Calendar API Quickstart";


    public static string GetEvents()
    {
        UserCredential credential = Login();

        return GetData(credential);
    }

    private static string GetData(UserCredential credential)
    {
        // Create Calendar Service.
        var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        // Define parameters of request.
        EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("The calendar ID to the calender I want to access");
        request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
        request.ShowDeleted = false;
        request.SingleEvents = true;
        request.MaxResults = 10;
        request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;

        Console.WriteLine("Upcoming events:");
        Events events = request.Execute();
        if (events.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
            {
                string when = eventItem.Start.DateTime.ToString();
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(when))
                {
                    when = eventItem.Start.Date;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", eventItem.Summary, when);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No upcoming events found.");
        }
        return "See console log for upcoming events";
    }

    static UserCredential Login()
    {
        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream = new FileStream(@"Components\client_secret.json", FileMode.Open,
            FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment
              .SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
               GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
              Scopes,
              "user",
              CancellationToken.None,
              new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        }

        return credential;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get a calendar list using the [`CalenderList API`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList) .

As per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts):

> Calendar List - A list of all calendars on a user's calendar list in the Calendar UI.

scrolling further down you find:

> **About calendarList entry resources**
>
> A calendar in a user's calendar list is a calendar that is visible in the Google Calendar web interface under My calendars or Other calendars:

Comment: Why would I wan't a calendar list?

`(I) want to access a public Google Calendar /.../ in order to look for upcoming events`

Comment: Read the section he posted that says "About calendarList entry resources"

Comment: Using the CalenderList only gives you information about either one (1) calendar or a list with all of your calendars. It has nothing to do with events, which where what the question was about. It clearly says so in the documentation that @NETscape linked to. It's even possible to try the methods there and none of them returns any events. If you look at my edit #2 in the question you see the solution, which, again, has nothing to do with CalendarList.

Comment: `which a want to access a public Google Calendar that I have added to my Google account`. To me that says how can I get access to different calendars because you already have the code for getting events.

Comment: Still, I changed one word in my original code and never had to use CalendarList to solve my problem. CalendarList isn't used for handling events, it's used for handling calendars. If I would have asked "How do I get information about all of my calendars or a specific one", then CalendarList would have been the answer indeed.

Comment: My comment states your question is not clear because you you say you want to access a Google Calendar that you added to your Google account. You also say accessing the events works fine and that what you can't figure out is how to select which calendar you want to access. Your hard-coded solution will not work when you want to switch calendars during run time.

Comment: I suggested edits to your question. My main concern is that you say the code worked--where the code retrieves events from a calendar--but you couldn't figure out how to select a specific calendar to retrieve the events from.  That is confusing, which prompted my answer... where you would first need a list of calendars to select from.  The code doesn't work if you're not getting any events in the first place. The whole purpose of the quickstart is to retrieve events from a calendar. If the code worked, then you would be seeing events. If anything, you meant the code compiles, but does not work.

Comment: But I sure did get events. So... Did it work or did it just compile? ;)